# Merging hashtables in PowerShell: how?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I am trying to merge two hashtables, overwriting key-value pairs in the first if the same key exists in the second.

To do this I wrote this function which first removes all key-value pairs in the first hastable if the same key exists in the second hashtable.

When I type this into PowerShell line by line it works. But when I run the entire function, PowerShell asks me to provide (what it considers) missing parameters to foreach-object.

```
function mergehashtables($htold, $htnew)
{
    $htold.getenumerator() | foreach-object
    {
        $key = $_.key
        if ($htnew.containskey($key))
        {
            $htold.remove($key)
        }
    }
    $htnew = $htold + $htnew
    return $htnew
}
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> mergehashtables $ht $ht2

cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Process[0]:
```

$ht and $ht2 are hashtables containing two key-value pairs each, one of them with the key "name" in both hashtables.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it is disappointing that this isn't built in, it is such a common need

Comment: @JoshPetitt check out this library-it even handles recursive merges: https://github.com/chriskuech/functional

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I see two problems:

1. The open brace should be on the same line as `Foreach-object`
2. You shouldn't modify a collection while enumerating through a collection

The example below illustrates how to fix both issues:

```
function mergehashtables($htold, $htnew)
{
    $keys = $htold.getenumerator() | foreach-object {$_.key}
    $keys | foreach-object {
        $key = $_
        if ($htnew.containskey($key))
        {
            $htold.remove($key)
        }
    }
    $htnew = $htold + $htnew
    return $htnew
}
```

Comment: I actually noticed the thing with modifying the collection and had added a third hashtable in another try. But the foreach-object problem remained. It didn't occur to me that the opening bracket had to be on the same line as for foreach-object because I was used to putting it on the next line.

Comment: I found I had to create a third hashtable in the function like this:  $htstatic = @{}; $htstatic += $htold; This gives me a new hashtable with the same contents as htold's to enumerate. Alternatively, I guess I can just remove from the other hashtable.

Answer (score 36):

### Merge-Hashtables

Instead of removing keys you might consider to simply overwrite them:

```
$h1 = @{a = 9; b = 8; c = 7}
$h2 = @{b = 6; c = 5; d = 4}
$h3 = @{c = 3; d = 2; e = 1}


Function Merge-Hashtables {
    $Output = @{}
    ForEach ($Hashtable in ($Input + $Args)) {
        If ($Hashtable -is [Hashtable]) {
            ForEach ($Key in $Hashtable.Keys) {$Output.$Key = $Hashtable.$Key}
        }
    }
    $Output
}
```

For this cmdlet you can use several syntaxes and you are not limited to two input tables:
Using the pipeline: `$h1, $h2, $h3 | Merge-Hashtables`
Using arguments: `Merge-Hashtables $h1 $h2 $h3`
Or a combination: `$h1 | Merge-Hashtables $h2 $h3`
All  above examples return the same hash table:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
e                              1
d                              2
b                              6
c                              3
a                              9
```

If there are any duplicate keys in the supplied hash tables, the value of the last hash table is taken.

---

(Added 2017-07-09)

### Merge-Hashtables version 2

In general, I prefer more global functions which can be customized with parameters to specific needs as in the original question: *"overwriting key-value pairs in the first if the same key exists in the second"*. Why letting the last one overrule and not the first? Why removing anything at all? Maybe someone else want to merge or join the values or get the largest value or just the average...
The version below does no longer support supplying hash tables as arguments (you can only pipe hash tables to the function) but has a parameter that lets you decide how to treat the value array in duplicate entries by operating the value array assigned to the hash key presented in the current object (`$_`).

**Function**

```
Function Merge-Hashtables([ScriptBlock]$Operator) {
    $Output = @{}
    ForEach ($Hashtable in $Input) {
        If ($Hashtable -is [Hashtable]) {
            ForEach ($Key in $Hashtable.Keys) {$Output.$Key = If ($Output.ContainsKey($Key)) {@($Output.$Key) + $Hashtable.$Key} Else  {$Hashtable.$Key}}
        }
    }
    If ($Operator) {ForEach ($Key in @($Output.Keys)) {$_ = @($Output.$Key); $Output.$Key = Invoke-Command $Operator}}
    $Output
}
```

**Syntax**

```
HashTable[] <Hashtables> | Merge-Hashtables [-Operator <ScriptBlock>]
```

**Default**
By default, all values from duplicated hash table entries will added to an array:

```
PS C:\> $h1, $h2, $h3 | Merge-Hashtables

Name                           Value
----                           -----
e                              1
d                              {4, 2}
b                              {8, 6}
c                              {7, 5, 3}
a                              9
```

**Examples**
To get the same result as version 1 (using the **last values**) use the command: `$h1, $h2, $h3 | Merge-Hashtables {$_[-1]}`. If you would like to use the **first values** instead, the command is: `$h1, $h2, $h3 | Merge-Hashtables {$_[0]}` or the **largest values**: `$h1, $h2, $h3 | Merge-Hashtables {($_ | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum}`.

More examples:

```
PS C:\> $h1, $h2, $h3 | Merge-Hashtables {($_ | Measure-Object -Average).Average} # Take the average values"

Name                           Value
----                           -----
e                              1
d                              3
b                              7
c                              5
a                              9


PS C:\> $h1, $h2, $h3 | Merge-Hashtables {$_ -Join ""} # Join the values together

Name                           Value
----                           -----
e                              1
d                              42
b                              86
c                              753
a                              9


PS C:\> $h1, $h2, $h3 | Merge-Hashtables {$_ | Sort-Object} # Sort the values list

Name                           Value
----                           -----
e                              1
d                              {2, 4}
b                              {6, 8}
c                              {3, 5, 7}
a                              9
```

Comment: way cleaner and more versatile  that other solutions.  Special appreciation for `$Input + $Args` technique, I haven't seen it before and it looks promising for extra-small utility functions which can process pipeline and array arguments

Comment: Awesome script Thanx for posting

Comment: @iRon, very interesting technique. Thanks for sharing. I've made a change to allow ordering. Rather than detract from your excellent answer and post my own answer, I've created a Gist: https://gist.github.com/arcotek-ltd/41f2326aca65d0dca7d7e669bde871d9. By all means, add it to your official answer, if you want.

Comment: @woter324, thanks for the feedback and suggestion. You might consider to make your script more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) by using the IDirectory interface like: `If ($Hashtable -is [System.Collections.IDictionary])` and the common `.Contains()` method but in general, note that the user might not expect a `[Ordered]` type as output (even it quiet easily converts into a `[HashTable]`). Another improvement to these scripts is [using the `get_Keys()` method rather than the `Keys` property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60810458/1701026).

Answer (score 9):

Not a new answer, this is functionally the same as @Josh-Petitt with improvements.

In this answer:

- `Merge-HashTable` uses the correct PowerShell syntax if you want to drop this into a module
- Wasn't idempotent. I added cloning of the HashTable input, otherwise your input was clobbered, not an intention
- added a proper example of usage

```sh
function Merge-HashTable {
    param(
        [hashtable] $default, # Your original set
        [hashtable] $uppend # The set you want to update/append to the original set
    )

    # Clone for idempotence
    $default1 = $default.Clone();

    # We need to remove any key-value pairs in $default1 that we will
    # be replacing with key-value pairs from $uppend
    foreach ($key in $uppend.Keys) {
        if ($default1.ContainsKey($key)) {
            $default1.Remove($key);
        }
    }

    # Union both sets
    return $default1 + $uppend;
}

# Real-life example of dealing with IIS AppPool parameters
$defaults = @{
    enable32BitAppOnWin64 = $false;
    runtime = "v4.0";
    pipeline = 1;
    idleTimeout = "1.00:00:00";
} ;
$options1 = @{ pipeline = 0; };
$options2 = @{ enable32BitAppOnWin64 = $true; pipeline = 0; };

$results1 = Merge-HashTable -default $defaults -uppend $options1;
# Name                           Value
# ----                           -----
# enable32BitAppOnWin64          False
# runtime                        v4.0
# idleTimeout                    1.00:00:00
# pipeline                       0

$results2 = Merge-HashTable -default $defaults -uppend $options2;
# Name                           Value
# ----                           -----
# idleTimeout                    1.00:00:00
# runtime                        v4.0
# enable32BitAppOnWin64          True
# pipeline                       0
```

Comment: Thanks sonjz, definitely an improvement!

Answer (score 6):

### In case you want to merge the whole hashtable tree

```
function Join-HashTableTree {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [hashtable]
        $SourceHashtable,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [hashtable]
        $JoinedHashtable
    )

    $output = $SourceHashtable.Clone()

    foreach ($key in $JoinedHashtable.Keys) {
        $oldValue = $output[$key]
        $newValue = $JoinedHashtable[$key]

        $output[$key] =
        if ($oldValue -is [hashtable] -and $newValue -is [hashtable]) { $oldValue | ~+ $newValue }
        elseif ($oldValue -is [array] -and $newValue -is [array]) { $oldValue + $newValue }
        else { $newValue }
    }

    $output;
}
```

Then, it can be used like this:

```
Set-Alias -Name '~+' -Value Join-HashTableTree -Option AllScope

@{
    a = 1;
    b = @{
        ba = 2;
        bb = 3
    };
    c = @{
        val = 'value1';
        arr = @(
            'Foo'
        )
    }
} |

~+ @{
    b = @{
        bb = 33;
        bc = 'hello'
    };
    c = @{
        arr = @(
            'Bar'
        )
    };
    d = @(
        42
    )
} |

ConvertTo-Json
```

It will produce the following output:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "d": 42,
  "c": {
    "val": "value1",
    "arr": [
      "Foo",
      "Bar"
    ]
  },
  "b": {
    "bb": 33,
    "ba": 2,
    "bc": "hello"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I just needed to do this and found this works:

```
$HT += $HT2
```

The contents of `$HT2` get added to the contents of `$HT`.

Comment: That works except when $HT2 has a key that already exists in $HT. Then the merge throws an exception.

Answer (score 4):

The open brace has to be on the same line as `ForEach-Object` or you have to use the line continuation character (backtick).

This is the case because the code within { ... } is really the value for the `-Process` parameter of `ForEach-Object` cmdlet.

```
-Process <ScriptBlock[]> 
Specifies the script block that is applied to each incoming object.
```

This will get you past the current issue at hand.

Comment: +1 for being direct and providing help with the current problem rather than simply providing a solution. To your a answer, does `ScriptBlock[]` mean that you can provide multiple script blocks? I need to look into that.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to point out that one should not reference base properties of the hashtable indiscriminately in generic functions, as they may have been overridden (or overloaded) by items of the hashtable.

For instance, the hashtable `$hash=@{'keys'='lots of them'}` will have the base hashtable property, `Keys` overridden by the item `keys`, and thus doing a `foreach ($key in $hash.Keys)` will instead enumerate the hashed item `keys`'s value, instead of the base property `Keys`.

Instead the method GetEnumerator or the `keys` property of the `PSBase` property, which cannot be overridden, should be used in functions that may have no idea if the base properties have been overridden.

Thus, [Jon Z's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800375/merging-hashtables-in-powershell-how/8800537#8800537) is the best.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most compact code to merge (without overwriting existing keys) would be this:

```
function Merge-Hashtables($htold, $htnew)
{
   $htnew.keys | where {$_ -notin $htold.keys} | foreach {$htold[$_] = $htnew[$_]}
}
```

I borrowed it from *[Union and Intersection of Hashtables in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823151/union-and-intersection-of-hashtables-in-powershell/33839784#33839784)*

Answer (score 2):

To 'inherit' key-values from parent hashtable (`$htOld`) to child hashtables(`$htNew`), without modifying values of already existing keys in the child hashtables,

```
function MergeHashtable($htOld, $htNew)
{
    $htOld.Keys | %{
        if (!$htNew.ContainsKey($_)) {
            $htNew[$_] = $htOld[$_];
        }
    }
    return $htNew;
}
```

Please note that this will modify the `$htNew` object.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to expand or simplify on [jon Z's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800375/merging-hashtables-in-powershell-how/8800537#8800537). There just seems to be too many lines and missed opportunities to use [Where-Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/Where-Object). Here is my simplified version:

```bsh
Function merge_hashtables($htold, $htnew) {
    $htold.Keys | ? { $htnew.ContainsKey($_) } | % {
        $htold.Remove($_)
    }
    $htold += $htnew
    return $htold
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function version that doesn't use the pipeline (not that the pipeline is bad, just another way to do it).  It also returns a merged hashtable and leaves the original unchanged.

```
function MergeHashtable($a, $b)
{
    foreach ($k in $b.keys)
    {
        if ($a.containskey($k))
        {
            $a.remove($k)
        }
    }

    return $a + $b
}
```

Comment: See improvements by sonjz