# powershell - add array to existing nested hash table

Tags: powershell, hash

I have an array or PSCustomObject called: `$results = @()`

I have a nested hash table called: `$allResults = @{}`

`$results |ft`, shows this in console:

```
Brokering        Name             WriteCacheSize   dFreeSpace   (and more...)   
---------        ----             --------------   ----------            
N/A              server0001       0,004            22,83             
N/A              server0002       0,004            21,86
```

`$allresults |ft` shows this:

```
Name                       Value                                                
----                       ----
server0001                     {SCOMStatus, PVSServer, RegistrationState, ServerLoad...}
server0001                     {SCOMStatus, PVSServer, RegistrationState, ServerLoad...}
```

The name is in common in both $. There should be a way to add the values in `$results` to `$allresults`, but I don't know how to do it.

I want everything in the hash nested table.  How can I add the values in the `$results` to the `$allresults`. The goal is having a nested table with every value.

Comment: Do you mean the `$allResults` hash table contains values that are your custom objects?

Comment: I do not have access to the actual objects to test it, but try: [`$results, $allresults | Union | ft`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428189/not-all-properties-displayed/44429084#44429084)

Comment: Or try: [$results, $allresults | Merge-Hashtables | ft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800375/merging-hashtables-in-powershell-how/32890418#32890418)

Comment: To convert a PSObject to a hash table (or visa versa), see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3740403/1701026

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add the values of an array to a hashtable you can loop through the array and use `$allresults.Add(<key>,<value>)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for their responses.
I finally achieved to do it. I created another object with custom properties, and then I fullfilled the hash table. 
This is the code:

```
$myObjectProperties = @(
"Brokering"
"PVSServer"
"Name"
"VDA"
"WMI"
"vDisk"
"dFreeSpace"
"WriteCacheSize"
"Spooler"
"CitrixPrint"
"Uptime"
"cFreeSpace"
"RunspaceId"
)
foreach ($element in $results){
    foreach ($property in $myObjectProperties){
        $allresults.$($element.Name).$property = $element.$property
    }
}
```